# Moving a shared_ptr to the method called on the object the shared_ptr points to

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, c++17

Given

```
struct X {
    void f(std::shared_ptr<X>);
};
auto x(std::make_shared<X>());
```

I can probably safely do

```
x->f(std::move(x));
```

in C++17 because `x->f` evaluated before the argument to `X::f` is constructed, right? As far as I know there is no such guarantee in earlier versions of C++. How can I achieve something similar in C++11 and C++14?

PS: Note the same also applies even when using `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: It also implies the question whether it is safe to destroy an object within/when leavng the scope of a member function of the very same object. Out of curiosity: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best one can do in C++11 and C++14 without changing the interfaces or using any obscure macros is

```
auto & refX = *x;
refX.f(std::move(x));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only have to introduce a sequence point between dereferencing x and calling f on that object. This provides a very readable solution to that.